# Checking for palindromes using array on ints, help (storing digits of long in array int)

Tags: java, arrays, int, long-integer, palindrome

Here is some code I wrote to check if a long is palindromic, using an array of integers. I did it like this to test my skills, (failed) so don't comment on better ways to check if a number is a palindrome.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class digextester {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String in = input.nextLine();
        long im = Long.valueOf(in).longValue();
        System.out.println(im);
        thing(im);
    }

    public static void thing(long im) {
        int l = 0;
        while (im > 0) {
            im = im / 10;
            l++;
        }
        System.out.println(l);
        int arrim[] = new int[l];
        for (int c = 1; c <= l; c++) {
            arrim[c] = ((int) (im - (im / 10) * 10)); // also tried = im%10
            im = im / 10;
        }
        int e = 1;
        int d = 0;
        while (e < (l / 2)) {
            if (arrim[e] == arrim[(l - e) + 1]) {
                d = 0;
            } else {
                d = 20;
                e = l;
            }
            e++;
        }
        if (d == 0) {
            System.out.println("pal");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not pal");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Exception I get in thread "main":

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at digextester.thing(digextester.java:27) - arrim[c] = ((int)(im-(im/10)*10)) ;
    at digextester.main(digextester.java:12) - thing(im);
```

Can someone please explain what is causing this Exception?

Comment: still, it would be easier to test the string directly, rather that the long.

Answer (score 2):

Your exception is due to the fact that array indices are from 0 to length - 1, not from 1 to length (i.e. `arrim[c]` causes an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception when `c == l`).

In addition, I'd extract the least significant digit from the long by `im % 10`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there is a logical error in the code. In your method

```
public static void thing(long im)
```

I suggest you add this:

```
long temp = im;
```

and in the for loop, change

```
arrim[c] = ((int) (im - (im / 10) * 10));
```

to

```
arrim[c] = ((int) (temp - (temp / 10) * 10));
```

If you do not do this, every number you input will be displayed as a palindrome.

Now for the exception.

In this fragment of your code,

```
for (int c = 1; c <= l; c++) {
arrim[c] = ((int) (im - (im / 10) * 10)); // also tried = im%10
im = im / 10;
}
```

first change to

```
for (int c = 0; c < l; c++)
```

Then in this part,

```
int e = 1;
    int d = 0;
    while (e < (l / 2)) {
        if (arrim[e] == arrim[(l - e) + 1]) {
            d = 0;
        }
```

change

```
int e = 1
```

to

```
int e = 0;
```

and

```
if (arrim[e] == arrim[(l - e) + 1])
```

to

```
if (arrim[e] == arrim[(l - e) - 1])
```

Then code should be working fine :)

Explanation: As other answers go, you have made c = 1 and not c = 0 in the for loop which causes the exception.

This is so because, for eg. if the number input is 1111, then value of variable l = 4 and hence array size is 4 ie. arrim[0] to arrim[3].

In the for loop when you say c=1 to c<=l (here 4), you are trying to assign values to arrim[1], arrim[2], ... arrim[4] and arrim[4] DOES NOT exist. This causes exception.

And in the second part you have made

```
int e = 1
```

and

```
if (arrim[e] == arrim[(l - e) + 1])
```

This causes the exception.

For example, if the input number is say, 1111 again, then value of variable l = 4.

arrim[0]=1, arrim[1]=1, ...., arrim[3]=1.

But in the if statement,
arrim[1] == arrim[(4 - 1) + 1)] ie.
arrim[1] == arrim[4] is being checked when there is NO arrim[4]. 
This is clearly the exception.

Comment: why do i have to introduce a new variable  (long temp) please explain            edit- its okay i see it know

Answer (score 0):

One alternative implementation:
**TestPalindrome Class**

```
package com.example.palindrome;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestPalindrome {
    private static TestPalindrome me;
    Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        me = new TestPalindrome();
        me.doWork();
    }

    private void doWork() {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number or Q to Quit");
        String inputValue = input.nextLine();
        while (inputValue != "Q") {
            long candidate = Long.valueOf(inputValue).longValue();
            boolean palindromatic = Palindrome.isPalindrome(candidate);
            System.out.println("Number " + candidate + " palindromatic ? "
                    + palindromatic);
            System.out.println("Enter number or Q to Quit");
            inputValue = input.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Palindrome Class**

```
package com.example.palindrome;

public class Palindrome {

    public static boolean isPalindrome(long number) {
        long reverse = 0;
        long value = number;

        while (value > 0 ) {
            long nextNumber = value / 10;
            long digit = value - nextNumber*10;
            reverse = reverse * 10 + digit;
            value = nextNumber;
        }
        return number == reverse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array "arrim" has only been initialized to a size of 1 ... meaning the only valid array element is at an index of 0... (arrim[0]).  Remember, arrays indexes start at 0.  Take a look here for more information on arrays: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

So, directly, your exception is coming from the following:

Your loop:

```
for (int c = 1; c <= l; c++) {
    arrim[c] = ((int) (im - (im / 10) * 10)); // also tried = im%10
    im = im / 10;
}
```

...starts by setting "c" to a value of 1. It then passes the termination test `c<=1` and progresses into the loop.
The first line of the loop trying to access `arrim[c]` -- which we know is `arrim[1]`.  Given we know that the arrim array only contains one element, at location arrim[0], any attempt to access an element of arrim that isn't at index '0' is going to result in a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a common error exception in java programming and you an read the nuts and bolts here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html.   The long and short of the exception comes down to: you tried to use an array index that was invalid (either smaller than zero or larger than .length-1 )